# Dual Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu Grub Issue

Tags: dual-boot

So today I dual booted Ubuntu and Windows 10 (my computer's original OS) and I do get the grub menu when i boot up my computer. The problem is the only options that grub gives me are :

-Ubuntu
-Advanced options for Ubuntu
-system setup
-Windows boot manager

and the only way to get to windows is by going to the windows boot manager and changing my boot order.

I was wondering if there was any way for windows 10 to show up in the grub menu so that I can just booth either Ubuntu or Windows upon starting rather than having to go through Windows Boot manager and changing my boot order every single time I want to change OS?

EDIT: clicking boot manger doesn't do anything; to get to the UEFI, I click on system setup...I don't really know why that's the case; I think there's a problem with my boot manager?

Comment: Do you have multiple items in your windows boot manager? if there is only one item in it, it will skip the windows boot manager and go straight to windows. Also, are you booting in UEFI or in BIOS/CSM?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? If so did you then turn off the always on hibernation or fast start up in WIndows. Grub will only boot working Windows or a Windows that is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk. Also Secure boot must be off, currently for grub to boot Windows.

Comment: i turned off secure boot and now when i click on boot manager; it boots me into windows! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

usually the fastest easy way to solve this kind of problems is directly reinstall Grub.

Did you try?

Grub automatically detect bootable installations and will make a new set of options into the boot menu.
So:

Boot in ubuntu, open terminal and do:

sudo grub-install /dev/XXX

**where /dev/XXX is your hard disk.**

I think you have Ubuntu and Windows on the same hard disk, so something like:

Ubuntu= /dev/sda1
Windows= /dev/sda2

In this case, to reinstall Grub you must do:

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

**To make it work properly, Grub must be installed "outside" a partition, so  into the /dev/sda Hard Disk, without number.**

Try that and if you are lucky at the next reboot you will have a working options menu =D

Bye!